# MODx - Editor role can't see files uploaded by Admin role

Tags: fckeditor, modx, modx-evolution

My MODx site allows users to upload files (pdf) through the back end.

However this is only working for users in the Admin role and not in my editor role who receive a "disallowed file type" message.

I can't see anywhere to set permissions, does anyone know where I should be looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries I found it, I had to add pdf to allowed file types in the user manager.